# Delphi - FieldByName.AsString - good practice

Tags: delphi

I've read an blog post(at this moment I can't find the link) where the author was saying that is faster to assign a local variable than using ADOQuery.FieldByName('...').asString or TSQLQuery.FieldByName('...').asString, when parsing an entire query with several thousands of records. I don't see the difference between

```
var aLocalField: TField;
....
aLocalField := ADOQuery.FieldByName('...');
..
ShowMessage(aLocalField.asString)
```

and by using directly

```
ShowMessage(ADOQuery.FieldByName('...').asString);
```

Blog post did not say anything about the database type or Delphi version. Is this solution related to one or another(and I'm not talking about obscure/custom database systems)?

Comment: Those two bits of code will perform identically.

Comment: Can you link that post? Perhaps you misunderstood something.

Comment: I'd guess it may be faster if you need to access the same value more than once (so instead of calling `FieldByName` multiple times you use a variable)

Comment: @RBA, if the blog post was [this one](http://fgaillard.com/2010/11/fieldbyname-findfield-too-convenient-to-be-honest/), the idea is to avoid the **repetition of `FindField` and `FieldByName`** (unless you use a modified and much speedier version of it).

Comment: Maybe it's this blog post: http://delphi.about.com/od/database/ss/faster-fieldbyname-delphi-database.htm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no noticeable performance difference between the two. I expect what you found was the difference between

```
DataSet.First;
while not DataSet.Eof do
begin
  ProcessValue(DataSet.FieldByName('Field').AsString);
  DataSet.Next;
end;
```

versus

```
Field := DataSet.FieldByName('Field');
DataSet.First;
while not DataSet.Eof do
begin
  ProcessValue(Field.AsString);
  DataSet.Next;
end;
```

If so, the latter is more efficient because `FieldByName` is a (relatively) slow function. If you don't need to call it more than once, don't call it more than once.

Comment: _If you don't need to call it more than once, don't call it more than once._   Hear! Hear!

Comment: _the latter is more efficient..._ It is also IMO easier to read, debug and maintain.

Comment: good to know. btw its 2012 and still no iterator for dataset , ill just wait another 10 years.

Comment: Exactly, Francois.  Clean readable code (that also happens to be nominally faster) smells Less.

Answer (score 5):

What makes sense is this:

1. If you have a CLASS (such as a TForm) not a local function, you either persistently create the fields you avoid the cost of repeated lookup (FieldByName).
2. If you don't use persistent fields (in a dfm), you could do a lookup once at runtime, and avoid the cost of repeatedly looking it up, if it is used either (a) more than once in the context of a single function, or (b) where it could be looked up once when the query is executed, and stored in a protected Field of an object, so that it can be reused for the life of the query or the object, as appropropriate.

Your contrived example has zero benefit, but I believe that repeated lookups of Fields when these repeated logical lookups are wasted, are perhaps a worthy thing to mention as "wasteful".

I see code like this all day, and it drives me nuts:

```
procedure TSomething.DoSomething;
begin
    fDataset.FieldByName('X').AsString = fDataset.FieldByName('X').AsString+'Y';
end;
```

The above code is made less readable by such repetitions, and such readability concerns, as well as error checking concerns are why I would avoid the above, and instead have a `fX:TField` field:

```
 TSomething = class(TBaseClass)
  protected
   fDataSet:TDataSet;
   fX:TField;

 end;
```

Now we can write

```
 fX.AsString := fX.AsString + 'Y';
```

I think people worry too much about Performance and not enough about quality, and long repeated subexpressions are a sign of "lack of quality" and "lack of thought" just as much as of "lack of concern for performance".

Comment: _I see code like this all day, and it drives me nuts._   Alas, you're not alone...

Comment: Hi Warren: +1. What you refer to as static fields are I think known as persistent fields (because the fields are persisted in the dfm as opposed to the IDE forgetting about them all the time :-)

Answer (score 1):

FieldByName use simple-search. if you want to choice more than one field.
this code is better

```
// Same Text in StrUtils(unit)
for I:=0 to DataSet.Fields.Count-1 do 
begin
  if SameText( DataSet.Fields[I].FieldName,'Field1') then
    Field1:=DataSet.Fields[I]
  else if SameText( DataSet.Fields[I].FieldName,'Field2') then
    Field2:=DataSet.Fields[I];
end;
DataSet.First;
while not DataSet.Eof do
begin
  ProcessValue(Field.AsString);
  DataSet.Next;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Read:

- [FieldByName, FindField: too convenient to be honest](http://fgaillard.com/2010/11/fieldbyname-findfield-too-convenient-to-be-honest/)
- [FieldByName, or why a Profiler is your friend](http://delphitools.info/2010/11/30/fieldbyname-or-why-a-profiler-is-your-friend/)